# Older CH main panel.....Do I need to add a ground bar?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

[image]

This is my 100 amp main panel. I've updated the outlets and am slowly getting around to changing out the old wiring. Do I need to add a ground bar to this panel, or just wire it back with neutrals and grounds to the same bar, as it currently has? I do have a roll of #6 solid copper wire to run a new ground wire, to replace the old stranded (what looks to be aluminum wire)....Thank you all.

Comment: This is my main and only panel in the house. The stranded at the top is what I assume you are seeing.........not at all messing with that. It's hard to see, but down around the middle of the bar, there is an older cloth covered stranded cable that runs down in the crawlspace and is clamped to the water pipe......I was just going to upgrade it to a solid copper wire.

Comment: Yeah, I finally spotted that & deleted my comment. It's not terribly obvious. You might want to add a driven rod as well, if the water pipe is your only ground.

Comment: I've got a ground rod driven, BUT it's at the opposite end of the house............think that's a big deal? Have two ground wires running from the panel to opposite ends of the house?

Comment: Not a problem. Just the (presumably already spent) cost of the wire. I have 5 grounds rods placed on the grounding cable going to my well casing (which is a 6th really big ground rod.)

Comment: Usually code deals with what you need as a minimum.  The only thing with more grounding is cost.

Comment: I believe that there needs to be some sort of protection and cable clamp around that piece of NM-B sticking up through the _big_ knockout in the bottom center of the panel. i.e. that knockout edge could be sharp and damage the jacket, leading to the need for a replacement.

Comment: I agree(d) when I found it and have since removed it and ran it up through a normal knockout with a connector.........somebody took a shortcut back in the 80's when installing central air.........smh

Answer (score 6):

Main panels the ground and neutral bars/buses are bonded together, so another ground bar would only be for making the wire placement neater.

Sub panels the ground and neutral bars/buses must separated and not bonded together.

Aluminum bars go good with aluminum wire.

New electrical work they want you to use torque bars or torque screwdrivers to tighten connections to specific torque values.  This is for all connections,panels,outlets, switches.